# Detect Multiple Keypresses in C - WinAPI Console App

Tags: c, winapi

How can I detect the multiple keypresses in the Windows Console app (written in C)?

Like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

Could someone can give an example.

I am currently using `kbhit` and `GetAsyncKeyState` to detect only one keypress.

Or there is a need for a workaround?

Comment: Please add a [mre] and explain what you expect and what you get, so others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your program can track the state "pressed" for the modifier keys, for example.

Comment: The documented way is to use [ReadConsoleInput()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput).  You'll get an INPUT_RECORD when the Q key is pressed, detected by checking the wVirtualKeyCode member.  The dwControlKeyState field tells you what modifier keys are active.

Comment: If you are already using `GetAsyncKeyState()` for one key, you can use it for multiple keys, eg: `if ( (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0) && (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU) < 0) && (GetAsyncKeyState('Q') < 0) )`

Comment: It was kind of a time tracking app and did a simple workaround with strings (the architecture is bloated, actually) ... but this one is much clear :) Thanks

Comment: Do you want this to be a global hotkey? In that case the system does everything for you already: See [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey).

Comment: Thank you for the RegisterHotKey. I didn't know about it.